# Types of current sensing in a MCU controlled synchronous buck-converter and there uses

Tags: buck, synchronous

I am trying to design a synchronous buck-converter driven by a PWM signal generated by a Atmel XMEGA microcontroller.
The input voltage comes from two series Li-Ion batteries so when they are fully charged the input voltage is at 8,4V and the circuit stops operating when the battery voltage decreases to 6,4V. The output current is a maximum of 40A and the nominal value will be around 20A.

The converter is operating at 100kHz and are using a 6µH(but I am starting to wonder if that isn't a little high), I haven't picked out output capacitors yet but it will be ether one large value ceramic or several small value ceramic.

One of the main uses for this converter is to regulate the heat of a heating element presenting a low resistance to the output(it will be capable of driving elements as low as 0,025Ω if I recall correctly but most often the resistance will be around 0,1Ω-0,2Ω), the resistance of the heating element(coil) will be measured at room temperature and that value is stored to be used to compare to the value of the resistance of the heating element as it's temperature is rising and that is the information used to regulate the temperature,the heating element are made out of SS316/L.

I plan to measure both input/output voltage and current, the input current is no mysteries but what about the output current?

I need to compute the output power and to be able to alternatively regulate the output by setting a desired power level(when temperature regulation isn't used).

But I don't understand and I can't find anything online explaining what the difference it of measuring the current through the inductor and the current after the inductor/capacitor.
Measuring the current through the inductor will provide the information needed for cycle-to-cycle current limiting as far as I know and I would guess that the current after the LC filter would be the average current.

But what I don't know is which one I need, or if I need both to be able to control the output current well enough to regulate the output power/temperature(by increasing and decreasing the output power as to maintain a steady temperature)?

Does anyone know about this?

Regards

Comment: Why use an inductor/capacitor if all you are doing is driving a heating element?

Comment: Well at frequencies such as 100kHz perhaps it wouldn't matter. I am designing this for use as a electronic cigarette and I begun by looking at the commercial devices sold and how they are made, and early devices used unfiltered PWM but the experience wasn't good and DC-DC converters with filter components where adopted. But now when you ask I realize that those devices used a much much lower frequencies and perhaps with 100kHz it at least sounds as one wouldn't be able to tell the difference. I have come to realize a few things and will change the question.